# Arrange elements in a list so that similar elements are farthest apart

Tags: python, sorting

**How can I sort a playlist so that songs by the same artists are spread as far as possible?**

Although I couldn't find one or figure it out, I assume there's some fast and simple way of doing this, which will work for all kinds of setups and also for two aspects: Let's say (un)sorting by artist and the genre so that additionally one genre is almost always followed by a different one. (so it's a nice mix)

So this is one exemplary playlist:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Song = namedtuple('Song', ('artist', 'title', 'length'))

# the length is not correct
Mozart_1 = Song('Mozart', 'Don Giovanni', 3.5)
Mozart_2 = Song('Mozart', 'Serenata Notturna', 2.98)
Mozart_3 = Song('Mozart', 'Violin Concerto No. 3 in G, 1st Movement', 8.43)
Bach_1 = Song('Bach', 'Air', 6.18)
Bach_2 = Song('Bach', 'Toccata in D Minor', 12.44)
Beethoven_1 = Song('Beethoven', 'Für Elise', 2.47)

playlist = [Beethoven_1, Mozart_3, Bach_1, Mozart_2, Mozart_1, Bach_2] # unsorted
```

And this would be one possible optimal outcome:

```
OPTIMUM = [Mozart_1, Bach_1, Mozart_2, Beethoven_1, Mozart_3, Bach_2]
```

Comment: The other question doesn't ask for how to achieve spreading for multiple aspects so that's no duplicate as far as I can tell.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually one answer for the question, that my question was said to be a duplicate of, has worked for me. So maybie my question is indeed a duplicate. Although if someone comes up with a faster non-random version I would still mark that answer as accepted. Here is my modified version:

```
import random
from collections import namedtuple, defaultdict
from operator import attrgetter

Song = namedtuple('Song', ('artist', 'title', 'length'))

# the length is not correct
Mozart_1 = Song('Mozart', 'Don Giovanni', 3.5)
Mozart_2 = Song('Mozart', 'Serenata Notturna', 2.98)
Mozart_3 = Song('Mozart', 'Violin Concerto No. 3 in G, 1st Movement', 8.43)
Bach_1 = Song('Bach', 'Air', 6.18)
Bach_2 = Song('Bach', 'Toccata in D Minor', 12.44)
Beethoven_1 = Song('Beethoven', 'Für Elise', 2.47)

playlist = [Beethoven_1, Mozart_3, Bach_1, Mozart_2, Mozart_1, Bach_2] # unsorted

# one possible optimum
# OPTIMUM = [Mozart_1, Bach_1, Mozart_2, Beethoven_1, Mozart_3, Bach_2]


def optimize(items, quality_function, stop=1000, randrange=random.randrange):
    length = len(items)
    no_improvement = 0
    best = 0
    while no_improvement < stop:
        i = randrange(length)
        j = randrange(length)
        copy = items[:]
        copy[i], copy[j] = copy[j], copy[i]

        q = quality_function(copy)
        if q > best:
            items, best = copy, q
            no_improvement = 0
        else:
            no_improvement += 1
    return items


def quality_maxmindist(items):
    s = 0
    for item in set(items):
        indcs = [i for i in range(len(items)) if items[i] == item]
        if len(indcs) > 1:
            s += sum(1. / (indcs[i+1] - indcs[i]) for i in range(len(indcs)-1))
    return 1. / s


def spread_equal_items_apart(items, key, stop=optimize.__defaults__[0]):
    keys, key_to_items = keys_and_key_to_items_dict(items, key)
    keys = optimize(keys, quality_maxmindist)
    re = []
    for k in keys:
        re.append(key_to_items[k].pop())
    return re


def keys_and_key_to_items_dict(items, key):
    key_to_items = defaultdict(list)
    keys = []
    for i in items:
        k = key(i)
        keys.append(k)
        key_to_items[k].append(i)
    return keys, key_to_items


if __name__ == '__main__':
    new = spread_equal_items_apart(playlist, attrgetter('artist'))
    print(new)
```

So `new` is now:

```
[Song(artist='Mozart', title='Don Giovanni', length=3.5),
 Song(artist='Bach', title='Toccata in D Minor', length=12.44),
 Song(artist='Beethoven', title='Für Elise', length=2.47),
 Song(artist='Mozart', title='Serenata Notturna', length=2.98),
 Song(artist='Bach', title='Air', length=6.18),
 Song(artist='Mozart', title='Violin Concerto No. 3 in G, 1st Movement', length=8.43)]
```

Answer (score 5):

I *think* this is not an unreasonable answer to spread the possibilities out (even if it doesn't meet your example):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

by_artist = defaultdict(count)
new_list = sorted(playlist, key=lambda L: next(by_artist[L.artist]))
```

Given a playlist of:

```
[Song(artist='Beethoven', title='Fur Elise', length=2.47),
 Song(artist='Mozart', title='Violin Concerto No. 3 in G, 1st Movement', length=8.43),
 Song(artist='Bach', title='Air', length=6.18),
 Song(artist='Mozart', title='Serenata Notturna', length=2.98),
 Song(artist='Mozart', title='Don Giovanni', length=3.5),
 Song(artist='Bach', title='Toccata in D Minor', length=12.44)]
```

It outputs:

```
[Song(artist='Beethoven', title='Fur Elise', length=2.47),
 Song(artist='Mozart', title='Violin Concerto No. 3 in G, 1st Movement', length=8.43),
 Song(artist='Bach', title='Air', length=6.18),
 Song(artist='Mozart', title='Serenata Notturna', length=2.98),
 Song(artist='Bach', title='Toccata in D Minor', length=12.44),
 Song(artist='Mozart', title='Don Giovanni', length=3.5)]
```

Comment: And if you add a random component too: `next(by_artist[L.artist]), random.random())` you get to shuffle the tracks around a little without sacrificing the spread.

Comment: What if your music selection looks like mine, with a lot of artists, but a few noticably over-represented.  If we had 500 songs by a range of different artists, and 500 by Mozart, wouldn't we end up with a good distribution of artists over the first half, including one by Mozart, followed by the 499-long Mozart super-block?

Comment: @femtoRgon True... lemme think...